# Basic npm + Webpack: why so many modules?

Tags: npm, webpack

I am just dabbling with npm and Webpack to try to understand how it all hangs together. I have create a very simple package.json file and ask npm to install webpack like this:

```
npm install webpack --save-dev
```

But as I do this, my npm_modules folder is filled up with 127 modules: align-text, ansi-wrap, crypto-browserify, optimist, punycode, etc., etc. When I use "npm install" in other projects that use Webpack, they do not seem to have this problem. They just have the dependencies they listed as devDependencies.

If I also add webpack-dev-server, the list grows to 192!

If the modules did not interfere, it would not be clean but there would not really be a problem. But I am trying to install webpack because I want to include my modules, and once webpack sees the node_modules dir it ends up making a super big output :(

Is this normal? Is there something I can do to not have so many modules?

Please accept my apologies for my bad English, and thank you very much for any advice you can send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since npm@3 dependencies are now [installed flat](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0).

You could verify that, by looking inside `node_modules/webpack/node_modules` of your "other projects", which you mentioned. Inside that folder, 
you should find the dependencies of webpack as well.

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.